# Jquery Error - Switch on / off link

Tags: jquery

I have a link text that acts as a switch on/off button and I'm trying to use it without any page reload.
When turned off, the link has a certain class, url and text value different from the turned-on state. (ie turned on it appears green / turned off it appears red )

A little below you have the jquery code I'm using for the moment.

```
$('.off').click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newlink = link.replace('off','on');
    $.get(link, function(data) {
    $('#front').html(data);
    $('#front').center().show();
    $('#background').show();
    if( data == "Button switched." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('on'); element.attr('class', 'on'); }
    });
    return false;
            });

$('.on').click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newlink = link.replace('on','off');
    $.get(link, function(data) {
    $('#front').html(data);
    $('#front').center().show();
    $('#background').show();
    if( data == "Button switched off." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('off'); element.attr('class', 'off'); }
    });
    return false;

          });
```

and the HTML element I'm talking about looks like this:
`<a href="engine.php?id=15&amp;switch=on" class="on">on</a>`

So, if the element that looks exactly like above is being clicked, the button is being switched to off and all the links attributes are being changed, but when I click the second time ( on the link with the new attributes ) it makes the ajax request and it's giving me the result in `#front` but it wont change the link's attributes again, as it should.

What's the problem?

Comment: You may want to try `removeClass()` http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ and `addClass()` http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ instead of changing the `attr`.

Comment: Just an observation, you could pretty much roll those two up into a single function and then call the swap depending on which is clicked. It'd be cleaner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are switching the classes so when it initially loads `.on` doesn't exist yet so no events are registered for that. You can solve this by using event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', '.off', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newlink = link.replace('off','on');
    $.get(link, function(data) {
    $('#front').html(data);
    $('#front').center().show();
    $('#background').show();
    if( data == "Button switched." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('on'); element.attr('class', 'on'); }
    });
    return false;
            });

$(document).on('click', '.on', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newlink = link.replace('on','off');
    $.get(link, function(data) {
    $('#front').html(data);
    $('#front').center().show();
    $('#background').show();
    if( data == "Button switched off." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('off'); element.attr('class', 'off'); }
    });
    return false;

   });
```

By the way try not to use `document`, instead use any container's selector that exists in DOM at any point in time. i.e `$('.somContainerSelector').on('click', '.off', function() {..`

You can try to simplify from having duplicate code in 2 handlers to one handler `$(document).on('click', '.on, .off', function() {` as the difference is all about the text `on` and `off`.

Comment: For efficiency sake, you should replace `document` with the element's direct parent.

Comment: Well, actually those classes will be used many times in a page. I'm having a table that has a button like above on each row.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai You can also simplify your code to have only one handler with both the selectors., as it just does switching of text in hyperlink href and class.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai I did not get your point. Using those `on`/'off' hyperlinks many times in a page will still work with this.

Comment: @PSL I think that may have been a response to my comment.  If these are all over the page then `document` selector may be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$('.off').click(function() {...`, the click handler is attached to all `.off` element which exist **at the time the code is executed**.  When this code executes, there are no `.off` elements.

You should probably just use a single `click` handler and then have some logic to determine which state it is currently in, or store the state in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The probleme is that even if you change the class, it still have the binding of `off` and never actually get the binding of `on`.

The binding are aplied on DOM ready. Since your tag only have `off` class, on is not applied and off will alvays trigger.

Use `.on()` binding like that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.off', function(){...})
$(document).on('click', '.on', function(){...})
//Document should be a selector of the closest non-dynamic parent.
```

and it will work.

Also, since the code is almost the same, you can wrap it in 1 function :

```
$('.off').click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var link = element.attr('href');
    var isOff = element.hasClass('off')
    var newlink = isOff ? link.replace('off','on') : link.replace('on','of')
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        $('#front').html(data);
        $('#front').center().show();
        $('#background').show();
        if( data == "Button switched." ) { 
            element.attr('href', newlink);
            element.text(isOff ? 'on' : 'off');
            element.toggleClass('on off'); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `on` will work if used as event delegation.  Just `$(".off").on("click"...` will fail in the same way `click` does.

Comment: I know, missed to specify. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if this works

```
$(document).on('click', '.on, .off', function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var newlink = link.replace('on','off');

        $.get(link, function(data) {
           $('#front').html(data).center().show();
           $('#background').show();
              if( data == "Button switched off." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('off'); element.removeClass('on').addClass('off'); } 
              else if( data == "Button switched." ) { element.attr('href', newlink); element.text('on'); element.removeClass('off').addClass('on'); }
        });

        return false;

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try. Replace your two click functions with this single one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.on, .off', function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var newmode = $element.hasClass('on') ? "off" : "on";
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var newlink = (link.match('on')) ? link.replace('on','off') : link.replace('off', 'on');
        $.get(link, function (data) {
                $('#front').html(data);
                $('#front').center().show();
                $('#background').show();
                if (data == "Button switched" + ((newmode == "off") ? " off" : "") + ".") {
                    element.attr('href', newlink);
                    element.text(newmode);
                    element.removeClass('on off').addClass(newmode);
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

Here's what this accomplishes:

1. Changes the click function to a $.on() function. I think switching the class back and forth was causing the $.click() function to lose its binding to the element. $.on() should prevent that
2. Removes the duplicate code you had in both click functions and unifies it all together.